# Is there a way to know the status of a systemctl process running in the host from a docker container(base image python:3.9)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to get the status of a systemctl service which is in the host from the docker container.

I tried to volume mount the necessary unit files and made the docker work in privileged mode. But still i get an error saying the status of the service is inactive while the status in the host is in active.

```
docker run --privileged -d -v /etc/systemd/system/:/etc/systemd/system/ -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -v /usr/lib/systemd/system/:/usr/lib/systemd/system/ test-docker:latest
```

Is there a way to achieve this or any equivalent way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

The way `systemctl` communicates with `systemd` to get service status is through a [d-bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) socket. The socket is hosted in `/run/systemd`. So we can try this:

```
docker run --privileged -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup test-docker:latest
```

But when we run `systemctl status` inside the container, we get:

```
[root@1ed9d836a142 /]# systemctl status
Failed to connect to bus: No data available
```

It turns out that for this to work, `systemctl` expects `systemd` to be pid 1, but inside the container, pid 1 is something else. We can resolve this by running the container in the host PID namespace:

```
docker run --privileged -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd --pid=host test-docker:latest
```

And now we're able to successfully communicate with systemd:

```
[root@7dccc711a471 /]# systemctl status | head
● 7dccc711a471
    State: degraded
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 2 units
    Since: Sun 2022-06-26 03:11:44 UTC; 5 days ago
   CGroup: /
           ├─kubepods
           │ ├─burstable
           │ │ ├─pod23889a3e-0bc3-4862-b07c-d5fc9ea1626c
           │ │ │ ├─1b9508f0ab454e2d39cdc32ef3e35d25feb201923d78ba5f9bc2a2176ddd448a
...
```

Comment: { docker run --privileged -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd --pid=host test-docker:latest } I tried to give this but it says the unit is not found. I tried to volume mount the unit from /usr/lib/systemd/system but after doing that it says that the status is inactive. what was the base image used in ur case ?

Comment: In my case I was using `fedora:35` (because that matches what I'm running on my host), and then simply `yum -y install systemd`.